# Jena Location Mapping failed to find configuration

Tags: eclipse, lucene, sparql, jena

i am working with Jena Text Search using SPARQL. It has succeed in compile time and run time but it doesn't show the desired result which is the result should show the URI and the intended text. It looks like error messages but i get the failed description below:

```
DEBUG org.apache.jena.util.LocationMapper  - Failed to find configuration: file:location-mapping.rdf;file:location-mapping.n3;file:location-mapping.ttl;file:etc/location-mapping.rdf;file:etc/location-mapping.n3;file:etc/location-mapping.ttl
DEBUG org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.JenaIOEnvironment  - Failed to find configuration: location-mapping.ttl;location-mapping.rdf;location-mapping.n3;etc/location-mapping.rdf;etc/location-mapping.n3;etc/location-mapping.ttl
```

The full codes show below:

```
public class JenaTextSearch {

static {LogCtl.setLog4j();
    BasicConfigurator.configure();}
static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("JenaTextSearch");



public static void main (String ...argv)
{
    Dataset ds = createCode();
    //loadData(ds, "data.ttl");
    queryData(ds);

}

public static Dataset createCode()
{
    //base data
    Dataset ds1 = DatasetFactory.create();
    Model defaultModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    defaultModel.read("to_index/data.ttl", "N-TRIPLES");
    ds1.setDefaultModel(defaultModel);


    //define the index mapping
    EntityDefinition entDef = new EntityDefinition ("uri", "text", ResourceFactory.createProperty(App.URI_PREFIX,"content"));

    Directory dir = null;

    try {
        dir = new SimpleFSDirectory(Paths.get("index")); //lucene index directory
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //join together into a dataset
    Dataset ds = TextDatasetFactory.createLucene(ds1, dir, new TextIndexConfig(entDef));

    return ds1;

}


public static void queryData(Dataset dataset)
{
    String prefix = "PREFIX email: <" + App.URI_PREFIX+">" +
            "PREFIX text: <http://jena.apache.org/text#>";

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Email's content contains 'good'");
    String query = "SELECT * WHERE " +
            "{?s text:query (email:content 'good')." +
            "?s email:content ?text." +
            "}" ;

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);
    try {
        Query q = QueryFactory.create(prefix+"\n"+query);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, dataset);
        QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qexec);
    }finally { dataset.end();}
    long finishTime = System.nanoTime();
    double time = (finishTime-startTime)/1.0e6;
    System.out.println ("Query "+String.format("FINISH - %.2fms", time));

    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("Email's content contains 'bad'");
    query = "SELECT * WHERE" +
            "{(?s ?score ?lit) text:query (email:content 'bad' \"highlight:s:<em class='hiLite'> | e:</em>\")." +
            "?s email:content ?text." +
            "}" ;

    dataset.begin(ReadWrite.READ);

    try {
        Query q = QueryFactory.create(prefix+"\n"+query);
        QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(q, dataset);
        QueryExecUtils.executeQuery(q, qexec);
    } finally { dataset.end() ; }
    finishTime = System.nanoTime();
    time = (finishTime-startTime)/1.0e6;
    System.out.println("Query "+String.format("FINISH - %.2fms",  time));
}}
```

is that a library problem or something? i use Jena 3.9 and 3.13 because it can completely each other, i think. please devise me. thank you.

Comment: those are just debug messages. Check a simple query first to see if the data has been loaded successfully, if that's the case your query simply doesn't match the data.

Comment: by the way, you do return `return ds1;` which is clearly wrong - it should be `return ds;` because you want to return the wrapper dataset which contains the Lucene index. That's most likely the main issue here

Comment: Those debug messages tell you that no remapping of names was found - that's normal.  For normal application use, set Jena logging to "INFO".